# How to update dictionary values based on values from another dictionary having same keys where values are list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that have the same keys. Both the dictionaries have values which are lists. I want to create a new dictionary which will have list as values and the list elements are based on a condition. The condition is to check if value of 1st list is present in the 2nd list and if it is present then that value should be replaced by 1 and the other elements will be replaced by 0.

For example:
Suppose there are two dictionaries as shown below

`dict_1={'1': [100], '2':[200],'3':[500]}`

`dict_2={'1': [100,105,300,600], '2':[100,300,900],'3':[600,300,500]}`

Now the resultant dictionary should be like this:

`dict_3={'1': [1,0,0,0], '2':[0,0,0],'3':[0,0,1]}`

The structure is same as `dict_2` with the elements of the list replaced. Since in `dict_1` the key `'1'` has element 100 in the value list, it will check in `dict_2` and if present that element will be replaced by 1 and the rest with 0 in the resulting `dict_3`.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [1 if val in dict_1[k] else 0 for val in v] for k,v in dict_2.items()}
{'1': [1, 0, 0, 0], '2': [0, 0, 0], '3': [0, 0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
{k: [int(x in dict_1[k]) for x in v] for k,v in dict_2.items()}
```

output:

```
{'1': [1, 0, 0, 0], '2': [0, 0, 0], '3': [0, 0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dict comprehension

```py
dict_1={'1': [100], '2':[200],'3':[500]}

dict_2={'1': [100,105,300,600], '2':[100,300,900],'3':[600,300,500]}

dict_3 = {k1: [int(dict_1[k1][0] == i) for i in v1] for k1,v1 in dict_2.items()} 
#{'1': [1, 0, 0, 0], '2': [0, 0, 0], '3': [0, 0, 1]}
```